# Does it make sense to say someone is your senior, such as a sibling?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

Does it make sense to say someone is your **senior**, such as a sibling?

I'm writing an essay about myself and was wondering whether or not it is a correct usage of the word.

Comment: It's fine to use the word senior with reference to anyone older in comparison. In the present example, the usual expression to use is 'senior to' as in "My brother B is **senior to** (elder to/ older than) me."

Comment: ODO: senior **1** Of a more advanced age: *he is 20 years senior to Leonard* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/senior

Answer (score 4):

*Senior* normally refers to someone who is higher in 'rank' than you, such as a manager at work. *Elder* is usually used when referring to someone older than you, e.g.

> He is my elder brother
>
> He is my eldest brother

Comment: 'Senior citizens' is a counterexample.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/senior Please see the first definition and example.